# C/C++ - Nested Class Inheriting from Enclosing Class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, member, nested

I would like to use nested classes as a part of an application I am building.  The first piece of code I have (header file, which I included some code for this question) is the following:

```
class Window {

public:
    indev::Thunk32<Window, void ( int, int, int, int, void* )> simpleCallbackThunk;
    Window() {
        simpleCallbackThunk.initializeThunk(this, &Window::mouseHandler); // May throw std::exception
    }
    ~Window();

    class WindowWithCropMaxSquare;
    class WindowWithCropSelection;
    class WindowWithoutCrop;

    virtual void mouseHandler( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param ) {
    printf("Father");
    }

private:
    void assignMouseHandler( CvMouseCallback mouseHandler );    

};

class Window::WindowWithCropMaxSquare : public Window {

public:
    WindowWithCropMaxSquare( char* name );
    virtual void mouseHandler( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param ) {
        printf("WWCMS");
    }

};

class Window::WindowWithCropSelection : public Window {

public:
    WindowWithCropSelection( char* name );
    virtual void mouseHandler( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param ) {
        printf("WWCS");
    }

};

class Window::WindowWithoutCrop : public Window {

public:
    WindowWithoutCrop( char* name );
    virtual void mouseHandler( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param ) {
        printf("WWOC");
    }

};
```

Now, I want to instantiate a `WindowWithCropMaxSquare` class in MAIN and execute the `mouseHandler` function.

In MAIN I have

```
Window::WindowWithCropMaxSquare *win = new Window::WindowWithCropMaxSquare("oopa");
win->mouseHandler(1,1,1,1,0);
```

However, this causes a problem at the linking stage. I got the following error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Window::WindowWithCropMaxSquare::WindowWithCropMaxSquare(char *)" (??0WindowWithCropMaxSquare@Window@@QAE@PAD@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\Nicolas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AFRTProject\AFRTProject\AFRTProject.obj

So, can anyone please let me know how to address this problem?

Comment: Do you implement the constructors anywhere?

Comment: Are you try to set public the class WindowWithCropMaxSquare?

Comment: No, I haven't yet implemented anything other than that. I thought an empty constructor would be ok :/

Comment: You need to implement the constructors, but the can be empty (i.e. just `{}`.)

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio As you can see that class publicly inherits its enclosing base class!
I have also tried declaring the three classes as private member classes and then use typedef to publicly access them.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish by nesting the derived class? Nothing about your current approach makes any sense to me. The names suggest to me that what you really want is to use composition: have `Window` include a `CropStrategy` member.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but in my eyes the structure of your classes (combining inheritance and nesting) is too complicated. You could consider putting all your classes in a namespace instead of nesting them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you very much it worked! It probably was a stupid thing to ask.
the reasons why I chose this structure is because I find nesting a more flexible structure as in some cases I might not choose to instantiate the inner class when a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things: a body for each constructor, and correct const'ness.

```
WindowWithCropMaxSquare( char* name );
```

is just a declaration without any definition (body). Empty constructor body, as you imply in your comment, would be

```
WindowWithCropMaxSquare( char* name ) {}
```

Also I very much suspect that

```
Window::WindowWithCropMaxSquare *win = new Window::WindowWithCropMaxSquare("oopa");
```

requires a constructor that takes `const char*` since you are giving it a constant (an rvalue):

```
WindowWithCropMaxSquare( const char* name ) {}
```

or

```
WindowWithCropMaxSquare( const string& name ) {}
```

The compiler will not give a constant as argument to a function that takes non-const since such function is indicating to you that it may modify the given argument, clearly not allowed for a constant.